# how to redirect to a specific app home page

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-home-page

I have 3 lightning apps in my system named 'AppA, AppB, AppC'. And I've created 3 home pages using lightning app builder. Now I want to generate a URL link and on clicking that should redirect to that specific app's home page.
For eg, on clicking the link, it should redirect me to the AppA's home page.
From AppMenuItem object, I've taken the startURL and tried with that. But it's redirecting to the classic page. I'm not sure how to generate the same for lightning experience.
Anyone with any idea, please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a simple lightning component with a link and action like below

appNav.html

```xml
<template>
   <lightning-button variant="brand" label="App A" title="App A" onclick={navigateApp}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

---

**Controller code**

appNav.js

```javascript
import { LightningElement} from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class AppNav extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

navigateApp() {
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'c__app',
        attributes: {
            apiName: <appDeveloperName>,
        }
      });
     }
 }
```

`appDeveloperName` is the developer name of your app.

Note the URL format would be as below `/lightning/app/c__<appdeveloperName>`

Comment: Is it possible to redirect the specific home page from Email Template?

Comment: Yes I have specified what the final url looks like in the answer! You can use that